# Extract or set private key parameters in cryptoki library

Tags: c, cryptography, nss

I ran into some issues writing a small test programme using the cryptoki library. I want (have) to get hold of the RSA private key (all its parameters). I thought about either generate keys and then extract the parameters or use already generated parameters to set the keys manually. So far, I don't get any of this working. Code is at the end of the post.

---

### Extraction

I know that there is the **C_GetAttributeValue()** with which I can extract attributes such as the public exponent or the modulus. That works for both public and private key objects but I get **CKR_ATTRIBUTE_SENSITIVE** error for when I try to extract private parameters from the private key object. Is there a way to extract these attributes? Can/Do I have to set certain parameters when logging into a session or during initialising?

### Setting Keys manually

My second approach was to read key material (generated with OPENSSL) from a file and use that for generating key objects with **C_CreateObject()**. The file contains all RSA parameters (n,e,d,p,q,dmp1,dmq1,iqmp). After reading, I convert them from ASCII to hex representation and store them in a **CK_BYTE[]**. So far so good. Now, when I pass all this to the **C_CreateObject()** in order to create a private key I receive a **CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID** error message. Creating a public key object the same way with the public parameters works. I verified that using **C_GetAttributeValue()** on the created public key object.
What am I missing for generating a private key object if this is even possible this way?
I suppose that **C_GenerateKeyPair()** always generates new keys no matter whether key material is provided or not, right?

---

### C Code

This is what I try to create the private key object with:

```
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKeys[NUMKEYS];
CK_KEY_TYPE kType= CKK_RSA;
CK_OBJECT_CLASS kClass = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY;
CK_BYTE id[] = {123};
CK_UTF8CHAR label[] = "An RSA private key object";

// sn,sd,se, etc contain the length of the respective parameter
CK_ATTRIBUTE privateKeyTemplate[] = {
            {CKA_CLASS, &kClass, sizeof(kClass)},
            {CKA_KEY_TYPE, &kType, sizeof(kType)},
            {CKA_TOKEN, &false, sizeof(false)},
            {CKA_PRIVATE, &false, sizeof(false)},
            {CKA_SENSITIVE, &false, sizeof(false)},
            {CKA_EXTRACTABLE, &true, sizeof(true)},
            {CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},
            {CKA_SUBJECT, NULL_PTR, 0},
            {CKA_DECRYPT, &true, sizeof(true)},
            {CKA_SIGN, &true, sizeof(true)},
            {CKA_LABEL, label, sizeof(label)-1},
            {CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},
            {CKA_MODULUS, modulus, sn},
            {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, publicExponent, se},
            {CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT, privateExponent, sd},
            {CKA_PRIME_1, prime1, sp},
            {CKA_PRIME_2, prime2, sq},
            {CKA_EXPONENT_1, exponent1, sdmp1},
            {CKA_EXPONENT_2, exponent2, sdmq1},
            {CKA_COEFFICIENT, coefficient, siqmp}
    };

    CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] = {
            {CKA_ENCRYPT, &true, sizeof(true)},
            {CKA_VERIFY, &true, sizeof(true)},
            {CKA_WRAP, &true, sizeof(true)},
            {CKA_MODULUS_BITS, &modulusBits, sizeof(modulusBits)},
            {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, publicExponent, se},
            {CKA_MODULUS, modulus, sn}
    };

rv = pFunctionList->C_CreateObject(hSession, privateKeyTemplate, NUM_ELEM(privateKeyTemplate), &hPrivateKeys[j]);
```

Comment: Hi Rick, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of generating a key pair and then reading it out is fine, you should however set the attribute `CKA_SENSITIVE` to false in the template of the private key. Note that it always depends on the token itself if such functionality is supported.

Usually when *extracting* private key information from a token you want to have it encrypted. Encryption of keys is called wrapping, and the possible extraction of sensitive information is managed by the `CKA_EXTRACTABLE` attribute.

> After reading, I convert them from ASCII to hex representation and store them in a CK_BYTE[].

The PKCS#11 token interface specifies precisely how to encode / decode attributes. Just trying formats haphazardly is not going to give any results.

Comment: I set the CKA_SENSITIVE attribute to false. Still not working. I don't want to wrap a key, I want to be able to read the key values so I know d,p,q, etc. What does "Note that it always depends on the token itself if such functionality is supported." mean? Is there a way to enable that support?

Comment: You might be able to use wrapping to extract the key and they unwrap. PKCS#11 is an API for C applications. A PKCS#11 token must contain all the API methods, but it may not actually implement all the possible functionality. E.g. smart cards usually restrict themselves to searching and signature generation/decryption with RSA keys.

Comment: Hi RIck, were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: No, sorry. I were not